LLamaIndex Workflow Context Memory Management
I am looking for a way to implement a RAG Chatbot which should keep the previous answer and questions from the current session in a short term memory and be able to answer followup question, I do not see anything from the documentation on how to implement that, I saw the chat engine documentation but saw no examples of implementing it in a workflow.
I was thinking whether to use external database with some time control mechanism and one of the nodes in the workflow to connect there and initiate the memory and pass along and for hte followup to have some human in the loop implementation which waits some time for followup quesiton and if nothing comes to delete the session but not sure whether this maskes sense as it seems overly complex :)
Looked through the workflow llamaindex documentation, looked through stackoverflow and google.

Kong Nopwattanapong published a blog post with regards to Building a simple RAG chatbot with LangChain.
Nopwattanapong concluded, the model isn’t perfect and there are still many things to add to and improve the model in future. However, this will hopefully give you a basic understanding of how to create an RAG chatbot and how vector databases work.
Another example that might help you in Building an LLM and RAG-based chat application using AlloyDB AI and LangChain. In this codelab you will learn how to deploy the GenAI Databases Retrieval Service and create a sample interactive application using the deployed environment. You may explore this github repository for more code level guide in GenAI Databases Retrieval App.
